# Finding the x value of the max y value in an array

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array of DataPoints, with an x and y value:

```
struct DataPoint: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let x: Double
    let y: Double
    
    var id: String { String(x/y) }
}
```

I am trying to get the x value that corresponds to the max y value. I am using this, but sometimes get an out of range error:

```
let dataPoints: [DataPoint] = await calculateDataPoints() 

if let index = dataPoints.indices.max(by: { dataPoints[$0].y < dataPoints[$1].y }) {
    return dataPoints[index].x
}
```

`calculateDataPoints()` is an async function.

Maybe there is another way to do this?

Comment: Drop the indices and compare directly, `dataPoints.max(by: { $0.y < $1.y }) `

Comment: @koen max() function is a built-in function in Swift's standard library,it is used to find the maximum value in a sequence of comparable elements, while max(by:) is used to find the maximum element in a sequence based on a custom sorting criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should first check if the `dataPoints` array is empty before finding the maximum value, in my scenario if the `dataPoints` array is empty, the `max(by:)` function will return `nil`,so the code inside the `if let` block will not be executed.

If you want to return a default value of `0.0` when the `dataPoints` array is empty:

```
let dataPoints: [DataPoint] = await calculateDataPoints()

if let maxDataPoint = dataPoints.max(by: { $0.y < $1.y }) {
    return maxDataPoint.x
} else {
    return 0.0
}
```

and using the nil-coalescing operator (??) to provide a default value of 0.0 simplifies the code.

```
let dataPoints: [DataPoint] = await calculateDataPoints()

return dataPoints.max(by: { $0.y < $1.y })?.x ?? 0.0
```

Comment: If the array is empty, I return 0.0.

Comment: You can simplify with with just `?? 0.0`

Answer (score 2):

After getting the `dataPoints`, you can get what you want like:

```
dataPoints.max { $0.y < $1.y }?.x
```

---

One line answer would be like:

```
return await calculateDataPoints().max { $0.y < $1.y }?.x ?? 0.0
```

Comment: @Freeman I don't think you are right about this code invoking `calculateDataPoints()` twice. Why would unwrapping the result and fetching its x value call `calculateDataPoints()` a second time? (I did a test using a function that returned an array like the above, and the function was only called once, which is what I would expect.)

Comment: @MojtabaHosseni, I did not know about the collection `max(by:)` function. thanks for that little nugget. (Voted)

Comment: Is there a difference between `max()` and `max(by:)` ?

Comment: I believe `max()` only applies to pairs of scalars that are Comparable. `max(by:)` operates on sequences. It takes closure that is passed pairs of objects to compare, which returns true if the right hand value is larger than the lefthand value. (I think I got that right.)

Comment: @Freeman your assumption about the execution of the `calculateDataPoints` is not true. It happens like -> calculate -> find max with the biggest `y` -> return its `x`.